# command line calendar with Monday as the first day of the week

Tags: unix

I'm trying to figure out how to use `cal` command on Linux/Debian to display Monday as the first day of the week instead of Sunday.

From what I see accordingly to cal's man page

```
-M      Weeks start on Monday.
```

But it doesn't seem to work on my machine:

```
cal -M
Usage: cal [general options] [-jy] [[month] year]
       cal [general options] [-j] [-m month] [year]
       ncal -C [general options] [-jy] [[month] year]
       ncal -C [general options] [-j] [-m month] [year]
       ncal [general options] [-bhJjpwySM] [-H yyyy-mm-dd] [-s country_code] [-W number of days] [[month] year]
       ncal [general options] [-Jeo] [year]
General options: [-31] [-A months] [-B months] [-d yyyy-mm]
```

Comment: You can use ncal -M -b. Seems like cal doesn't support the -M option in all version of unix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cal` doesn't support <kbd>-M</kbd> option in all UNIX versions.

Alternatively, you can use `ncal -M -b` to get the desired output.

```
      May 2022        
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su  
                   1  
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15  
16 17 18 19 20 21 22  
23 24 25 26 27 28 29  
30 31
```

Credits:

[How to display calendar in terminal with Monday as the start of the week](https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2019/01/02/how-to-display-calendar-in-terminal-with-monday-as-the-start-of-the-week/)

[Unix - Monday as first day](https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/160509-monday-first-day.html)